# Activity not launching when phone is held in landscape orientation

Tags: android, android-activity

The activity launches and works well when phone is held in portrait orientation but when I launch my app by holding the phone in landscape, either the app doesn't start or screen goes black for a millisecond and nothing happens. The problem goes away when I remove this from the code

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

but it is essential as my application will only be supporting portrait. What could be the problem?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this line in your menifests activity tag .

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" />
```

and remove

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

from your activity

Comment: That's the correct answer.Exactly this is what you should do.

Answer (score 3):

Remove this line

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

The above line will make the Activity to stay at Portrait mode. Just Add SensorPortrait mode.

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
```

in manifest.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it @chandankumarkushwaha

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from code

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Add the orientation layout like this:

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```